# $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, the number of function $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that for all $x\in S. \;\;f(f(f(x)))=x$ and $f(x)-x$ is not divisible by $3$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

> Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, the number of function $f:S\rightarrow S$ such that for all $x\in S. \;\;f(f(f(x)))=x$ and $f(x)-x$ is not divisible by $3$

**My solution for $f(f(f(x)))=x$**

I started with set containing $3$ elements i.e. $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and satisfying $f(f(f(x)))=x$, so total such functions are $3$.

Now, if set $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ then total number of functions satisfying $f(f(f(x)))=x$ are $9$

Now, if $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\} $ then total functions satisfying $f(f(f(x)))=x$ are $21$.

Similarly if $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, then total functions satisfying $f(f(f(x)))=x$ are $5769$.

But How do I find such that $f(x)-x$ is never divisible by $3$ and $f(f(f(x)))=x$?

**Please Help me find such functions**

After some hint from @calvin lin Here is further solution:
Let's partition $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ in three sets as $A=\{1,4,7\}, B=\{2,5,8\}, C=\{3,6,9\}$.

Elements of set $A$ must be connected to set $B$ or set $C$ if these are not connected to $B$ or $C$ then $f(x)-x$ will multiple of $3$.

Now if one element of $A$ is selected lets say $1$ then $f(1)$ can be chosen in $6$ ways as it $f(1)$ can take values from $\{2,5,8,3,6,9\}$

Let's say $f(1)=8$, then $f(8)$ can take values from set $\{3,6,9\}$ only. Otherwise $f(x)-x$ will not satisfy. For example let's say $f(8)=4$ then $f(4)$ must be $1$ but as we can see $f(4)-4$ is divisible by $3$. So $f(8)$ can be chosen in $3$ ways. let say $f(8)=3$

Now after selecting $f(8)$ and $f(1)$ as $3$ and $8$ we are forced to connect $f(3)$ with $1$ because we have to satisfy $f(f(f(x)))=x$ condition.

Also we can have $f(8)=1, f(1)=3, f(3)=8$

So total $36$ functions are possible when $f(1)=8$

Now I want to know that Did I do it correct or I am doing any mathematical error?

**New Update:** Actually there are $18$ function Here I've listed all $9$ functions

$ f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=1$

$f(1)=2, f(2)=6, f(6)=1,$

$f(1)=2, f(2)=9, f(9)=1$

$f(1)=5, f(5)=3, f(3)=1$

$f(1)=5, f(5)=6, f(6)=1$

$f(1)=5, f(5)=9, f(9)=1$

$f(1)=8, f(8)=3, f(8)=1$

$f(1)=8, f(8)=6, f(6)=1$

$f(1)=8, f(8)=9, f(9)=1$

Similarly when $f(1)=3$ or $f(1)=6$ or $f(1)=9$

Comment: Do you have a quick way of counting the number of functions satisfying $f(f(f(x))) = x$, or was it through tedious tabulation?

Comment: I calculated functions for set containing $3,4,5,6$ elements then I searched such sequence and then I found https://oeis.org/search?q=21%2C81%2C351&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Hint: Think about how the function partitions S into cycles of what length. $\quad$ In particular, $f(x) \neq x$ implies that we don't have any fixed points, and hence we must have 3 3-cycles.

Comment: I think you can solve this by 1) think in the cycle decomposition of the permutation (what are the possible cycles that satisfy the first constraint $f(f(f(x)))=x$?); and 2) given the cycles, choose the elements for each cycle, satisfying the second constraint $f(x) - x mod 3 \neq 0$,

Comment: Can you show the (possibly minor) step for "So total
36 functions are possible when (1)=8"? Where did the 36 come from?

Comment: @CalvinLin I've listed $9$ such functions

Comment: Sortof. Note that for each version of the function, you have to extend it out to the entire space $\{1, 2, \ldots, 9 \}$. So, what you have is 9 cases, rather than 9 functions. $\quad$ Each case behaves similarly. How many functions does each case have?

Comment: @CalvinLin There are $6\choose 1$ ways to select one elemet in set $B$ or $C$ for $f(1)$, after selecting $f(1)$ there are $3\choose 1$ ways to select image for set $B$ to set $C$ after that we are forced to image element of $C$ to element of $A$. Now select one image for $f(4)$ from set $B$ or set $C$, now there are only four elements left in $\{2,5,8,3,6,9\}$ , so we can do this in $4\choose 1$ ways. After selecting $f(4)$ in set $B$ there is only two elements left in $\{3,6,9\}$ because one element is already mapped.

Comment: Now $f(8)$ can be mapped to set $\{2,5,8,3,6,9\}$ in only two ways because four elements are already mapped and this can be done in $2\choose 1$ way. Set elements are forced to map with remaining elements So there are total ${6\choose 1} \cdot {3\choose 1} \cdot {4\choose 1} \cdot {2\choose 1}$ = 144

Comment: I disagree with "Set elements are forced to map with remaining elements ". You're still missing the number of ways for $f(7)$, as it can go to either element. $\quad$ IE The function is completely defined if we know $f(1), f(f(1)), f(4), f(f(4)), f(7)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observations towards a solution. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

1. $f(f(f(x))) = x$ means that either we have

   - $f(x) = y, f(y) = z, f(z) = x$ OR $f(x) = x$ for each $x$.
   - However, $f(x) = x$ is  disallowed by "$f(x) - x$ is not a multiple of 3   ".
   - Thus, S can be partitioned into sets of 3.
2. Consider such a set $\{x, y, z \}$.

   - Show that $f(x) - x, f(y) - y, f(z)- z$ is not a multiple of 3 IFF $ \{ x, y, z \pmod{3} \} = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$.
   - For each valid set, there are 2 ways to define the function. IE $f(x) = y, f(y) = z, f(z) = x$ OR $f(x) = z, f(y) = x, f(z) = y$.
3. How many partitions into valid sets of 3 are there?

   - We want sets of the form $ \{a_1, a_2, a_3 \}, \{b_1, b_2, b_3 \}, \{ c_1, c_2 , c_3 \}$ were $a_i \equiv i \pmod{3} $ (and similarly.
   - WLOG we may let $a_1 = 1, b_1 = 4, c_ 1 = 7 $, since order doesn't matter.
   - We have $3!$ ways to order the $b_i$ and $3!$ ways to order the $c_i$.
4. How many functions are there?

   - Since each set can be defined in 2 ways, and each partition has 3 sets, hence each partition leads to $ 2^3 = 8$ functions.
   - Hence the total number of functions is $ 6 \times 6 \times 8 = 288$.

Comment: I've added further solution. Can you please tell me if I did anything wrong?

Comment: can you send your's detailed solution?

Comment: @mathophile I edited more details in. If there is something specific that you don't understand, please state it and explain what you're having difficulty with. You should see a lot of similarity with your writeup.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from @calvin Lin Here is my solution to above Problem:

**Understanding The problem:**

First divide given set in $3$ sets say $A=\{{1,4,7\}}$, $B=\{2,5,8\}$, $C=\{3,6,9\}$.

**First thing** Elements of set $A$ or $B$ or $C$ cannot be mapped to themselves because in this case we will have $f(x)-x$ will be  divisible by $3$.

**Second thing** elements of $A$ can be mapped to set $B$ or set $C$ other. If element of set $A$ is mapped to set $B$ then element set $B$ will be mapped to set $C$ and element of set $C$ will be mapped to set $A$ **OR**  If element set $A$ is mapped to $C$ then element of $C$ will be mapped to set $B$ and elements of $B$ will be mapped to $A$

For example $f(1)=2, f(2)=3, f(3)=1, f(4)=6, f(6)=5, f(5)=6, f(7)=8, f(8)=9, f(9)=7$.

---

**Now Solve Problem:**

Now let map $1$ to any one element of set $B$ or $C$ which can be done in $6\choose 1$ ways. Let say $f(1)=3$

Now $3$ is from set $C$ so it must be mapped to element of Set $B$ which can be done in $3\choose 1$. Let say $f(3)=8$ now we are forced to map $8$ to $1$ othwerwise we will not have $f(f(f(x)))=x$.

---

Now map $4$ to remaining element in $B$ or $C$ $\bigg(\text{there are four elements left to map}\; 4 \;\text{with} \{6,5,9,2\}\bigg)$ which can be done in $4 \choose 1$

Let say $f(4)=2$ now we have to map $2$ to remaining element in set $C$ i.e. we have to map it to ${6,9}$ which can be done $2\choose 1$ ways let say $f(2)=6$ And now we forced to map $6$ to $4$ otherwise we will not have $f(f(f(x)))=x$

---

Now map $7$ to remaining elements in $B$ or $C$ $\bigg(\text{there are 2 elements left to map i.e.} \{5,9\} \bigg)$ which can be done in $2\choose 1$ ways. Let say $f(7)=9$. Now we have to map $9$ to $7$ only

**So final answer will be $6\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2\cdot 2=288$**

Other solutions are also welcome